# Submit a form **with a page refresh** using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

The following code changes the configuration of a Grid control, but this reconfiguration only happens after a page refresh occurs.

**How can I automate the user clicking the submit button?**  All the jQuery samples I see involve AJAX, but since I'm in the unique situation of needing to refresh the page, no one seems to have a sample available

```
<% using (Html.Configurator("The grid should...")
              .PostTo("Details", "TLSWorkflow")
              .Begin())
   { %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= Html.CheckBox("grouping", false, "allow <strong>grouping</strong> of data")%></li>
        <li><%= Html.CheckBox("filtering", false, "allow <strong>filtering</strong> of data")%></li>
        <li><%= Html.CheckBox("paging", false, "have <strong>pages</strong> with 10 items")%></li>
        <li><%= Html.CheckBox("ajax", true, "make <strong>AJAX</strong> requests")%></li>
        <li><%= Html.CheckBox("scrolling", true, "show a  <strong>scrollbar</strong> when there are many items")%></li>
        <li><%= Html.CheckBox("sorting", true, "allow <trong>sorting</strong> of data")%></li>
        <li><%= Html.CheckBox("showFooter", false, "show footer")%></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="t-button" type="submit">Apply</button>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your form an ID and call `submit` on it:

```
<form id="myform">...</form>
```

In plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('myform').submit();
```

or using jQuery:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("selector for your form here").submit();

// OR

$("button.t-button").click();
```

(By the way, you're hardly in a unique situation here.)